# Find a line in a file and add something to the end of the line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, sed

**How can I identify a line start with a special pattern and add something to the end of the line?**

if the pattern that should be added is not already appended

Let's say I'd like to find a specific line in the host file either by the pattern at the beginning may be an ip-address or by the comment that is above the line

An example may be:

```
#This is your hosts file

127.0.0.1 localhost linux 

#This is added automatically 

192.168.1.2 domain1. com 

#this is added automatically to 

192.168.1.2 sub.domain1.com www.domain1.com
```

How do I tell bash when you find the IP I tell you. go ro the lines end and add something

or the other case

When bash finds the comment `#This is added automatically`

go down by 2 and than go to the end of the line  and add something

You see I'm a beginner and don't have any Idea what to use here and how. Is dis done by sed? or could this be done with grep? do I have to learn AWK for that stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following:

Textfile:

```
[root@yourserver ~]# cat text.log 
#This is your hosts file

127.0.0.1 localhost linux 
[root@yourserver ~]#
```

bash script:

```
[root@yourserver ~]# cat so.sh 
#!/bin/bash

_IP_TO_FIND="$1"

# sysadmin 101 - the sed command below will backup the file just in case you need to revert

_BEST_PATH_LINE_NUMBER=$(grep -n "${_IP_TO_FIND}" text.log | head -1 | cut -d: -f1)
_LINE_TO_EDIT=$(($_BEST_PATH_LINE_NUMBER+2))
_TOTAL_LINES=$( wc -l text.log)
if [[ $_LINE_TO_EDIT -gte $_TOTAL_LINES ]]; then
   # if the line we want to add this to is greater than the size of the file, append it
  sed -i .bak "a\${_LINE_TO_EDIT}i#This is added automatically\n\n192.168.1.2 domain1. com" text.log
else
  # else insert it directly 
  sed -i .bak "${_LINE_TO_EDIT}i\#This is added automatically\n\n192.168.1.2 domain1. com" text.log
fi
```

Usage:

```
bash ./so.sh 127.0.0.1
```

Simply enter in the ip address you're trying to find and this script matches on the first occurrence of it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this great example. This is very specific to my example. The example was just chosen, because i had no other idea. I'll have a look into it and try to understand what you do later on my learning path.

Comment: I have no problem explaining everything, will add some comments now to show you how/why i did those things! @user121261

Comment: oops, just saw someone answered already, glad you found your solution!

Answer (score 9):

This will add some text to the end of the line with a pattern "127.0.0.1".

```
grep -F "127.0.0.1" file | sed -ie 's/$/& ADDing SOME MORE TEXT AT THE END/g'
```

Following will add to the line in the file that begins with `127.0.0.1` via sed :

```
sed -ie 's/^127.0.0.1.*$/& ADDing MORE TEXT TO THE END/g' file
```

TO do the same, you can also use `awk` :

```
awk '/^127.0.0.1/{print $0,"ADD MORE TEXT"}' file > newfile && mv newfile file
```

- EDIT

If you want to call the IP address through a variable then syntax might be a bit different :

```
var="127.0.0.1"
grep -F "$var" file | sed -ie 's/$/& ADD MORE TEXT/g'
sed -ie "s/^$var.*$/& ADD MORE TEXT/g" file
awk '/^'$var'/{print $0,"ADD MORE TEXT"}' file > newfile && mv newfile file
```

Comment: This is a great example. It shows three difernet ways with grep sed and awk, too. Also you are as general as possible. Thank you.

Comment: I've seen you've escaped the $ sign. Does that mean that your example just work with text but not with variables?

Comment: this does the job almost complacently but what if i like to force sed to write the ADDD MOR TEXT string each time the script runs to the line that starts with var

Comment: @user121261 You have been very inconsistent! The way it is currently written will add "ADD MORE TEXT" to the end of the line each time it runs. You need to modify the file interactively with the `-i` option. See my edit.

Comment: the first command gives a "sed: no input files" error with sed 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

This inline sed should work:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^192\.168\.1\.2.*$/& ADDED/' hosts
```

1. This sed command find lines that start with `192.168.1.2`
2. If found it adds `ADDED` at the end of those lines

Comment: How to do the inverse?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Please clarify what you want from this command.

Comment: That one had a lot of bugs. I fixed them here: https://github.com/Polycademy/add-etc-hosts But make sure to backup your /etc/hosts