# Find line and append text at the end does not work

Tags: linux, bash

What I like to do is to append some extra text at the end of the searched line.

I have found solution here:
[Find a line in a file and add something to the end of the line in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877229/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-add-something-to-the-end-of-the-line-in-bash)

But when I tried to do it either with sed or awk instead of appending it to the end, it replace the searched string.

My command:

```
sed 's/^string_for_search.*/& text_to_append/' file
```

Have I done something wrong or is it appropriate behaviour?

Comment: What is your input? What output is coming if you run the command? What is the expected output?

Comment: that's not normal, the `&` in your replacement pattern refers to the matched text (the whole line) and the text_to_append should therefore be appended. See it [here](https://ideone.com/boOMkm) in action

Comment: Ah, maybe a Carriage Return `\r` character hidden in your replacement pattern or source data, it might give you the illusion the line is overwritten. Check this out (possibly with `cat -A`) especially if some of your data comes from a Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if your source file (or less likely your `sed` command itself) contains a Carriage Return character (ASCII 0x13, often written as `\r`).

Those are one of the two characters that compose a Windows linefeed so your source file would be likely to contain them if it was created on Windows. On Linux however they are interpreted literally as a signal to ["return the carriage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Typewriters) and start writing back at the start of the line.

A file with the following content :

```
string_for_search\r\n
string_for_search\r\n
whatever\r\n
```

Would be transformed by your sed command into

```
string_for_search\r text_to_append_which_i_assume_is_longer\n
string_for_search\r text_to_append_which_i_assume_is_longer\n
whatever\r\n
```

which would be displayed as follow :

```
 text_to_append_which_i_assume_is_longer
 text_to_append_which_i_assume_is_longer
whatever
```

You can check if that's your actual problem by piping your output to `cat -A` which displays special characters : you should expect to see your original line followed by a `^M` representing the carriage return, itself followed by your replacement pattern and a `$` representing the `\n` linefeed :

```
string_for_search^M text_to_append_which_i_assume_is_longer$
string_for_search^M text_to_append_which_i_assume_is_longer$
whatever^M$
```

If that is indeed the problem then the solution is to remove the `\r` from the source file, which you can do by using the `dos2unix` utility if available, or `tr -d '\r'`. The software which produces your data might also have settings to avoid using Windows-styled linefeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
sed 's/^\(string_for_search.*\)/\1 text_to_append/' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat ~/tmp/t
Hello
World

$ sed 's/\(Hello.*\)/\1, hello/' ~/tmp/t
Hello, hello
World
```

Comment: OP's syntax works well in the general case, the `&` they use in the replacement pattern is the same as `\0` : a reference to the whole match. See [here](https://ideone.com/qtFVE1) for instance